# Redirect to react route with data when user clicks verify email button (Laravel Controller)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send some data or even just a message to my front end when I redirect a user on email verification click.

The click works fine and the verified_at field gets updated and then using redirect('/login') I get back to the correct react component. What I would like to do is display a message here saying something like "Cool, email verified, you can now login"

```php
public function verify(Request $request) 
{
    $userID = $request['id'];

    $user = User::findOrFail($userID);

    $date = date('Y-m-d g:i:s');

    // update email verified_at field
    $user->email_verified_at = $date; 

    $user->save();

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

I have also tried doing something like

```php
return redirect('/login')->with('blah blah blah');
```

Any ideas on how I can go about this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done is to add the id with the `redirect('/login/' . $id)`. This way I can use the id to get the user info again from the front end.

Probably not the best solution, but it works for now until I can work out something better

*(answered by questioner)*